# Ruby on Rails database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

I used scaffold to generate a db table, model, and controller for something called 'pins' with one string column in the table called description. The specific call was:

```
rails g scaffold pins description:string
```

In the pins_controller file it generated, it has the following code snippet:

```
def index
    @pins = Pin.all
end
```

Is the `Pin.all` call querying all the pins from the DB? Is `.all` an SQL call or a Ruby on Rails method? The code works on my test website I just want to understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: that is part of activerecord which will talk to db to make sql. if you do 'rails console' and do Pin.all, you should see what kind of sql call is generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the Pin.all call querying all the pins from the DB?

Yes, it is. An easy way to check is using `rails console`. When you run `Pin.all` in the console, it will show you something like:

```
2.1.2-perf :005 > Pin.all
  Pin Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "pins".* FROM "pins"
 => []
```

> Is `.all` and SQL call or a Ruby on Rails method?

`all` is an `ActiveRecord` method which will execute the SQL query. Read the [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/all/class) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

`all` is a Rails ***ActiveRecord method*** which gives you ***all the records*** when you applied on a ***ActiveRecord model***.

Here `Pin.all` returns all the existing records in the ***pins*** table. The equivalent ***SQL*** query which runs in the background is

```
SELECT "pins".* FROM "pins"
```

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) is an ORM (object relational mapping) which is basically a design pattern that enables you to access a relational database from an object oriented programming language (like Ruby).

Here you are using the ActiveRecord class method `.all` which returns all instances of Pin.

`.all` is converted into sql in the background so really what you are doing is:

```
SELECT "pins".* FROM "pins"
```